# Writing column of strings to CSV without quotation marks

Tags: python, string, csv, io

I want to write the list

```
someList=["a=1.0,2.0,3.0","b=1.0,2.0,3.0"]
```

to a single-column, two-row file which looks like (with no quotation marks around each row):

```
a=1.0,2.0,3.0
b=1.0,2.0,3.0
```

However, if I use the following code:

```
import csv
myfile = open("/home/user/fileName", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
for c in someList:
    wr.writerow(c)
```

then it won't give what I want:

```
a,=,1,.,0,",",2,.,0,",",3,.,0
b,=,1,.,0,",",2,.,0,",",3,.,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is already formatted, write the entire list into a file using the [`write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) method of the file object. Just ensure to add the newline as the line delimiter to join the lines:

**Implementation**

```
with open("/home/user/fileName", "w") as fin:
    fin.write('\n'.join(someList))
```

**Output**

```
a=1.0,2.0,3.0
b=1.0,2.0,3.0
```

Comment: This won't write a final newline character to the file, something many text editors can be a bit upset about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have never encountered issues without a trailing newline. Do you have an example of such an editor?

Comment: It's not just text editors, tools processing files may also (incorrectly) assume that every line has a line separator at the end. I don't have a direct editor example at the moment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `You should also not use .writelines()`. That's my bad. I originally started with a sequence, but later forgot to change it to `write`

Answer (score 1):

Your lines are *already* formatted; they are not CSV rows.

Just write the data directly to the file, with newlines:

```
with open("/home/user/fileName", 'w') as myfile:
    for line in someList:
        myfile.write(line + '\n')
```